# how to wait an exec finishes to write in pipe in C

Tags: c, pipe, exec

I'd like to know how to wait for my exec finish to write in an fd before use it?
The problem is the fact that not all of my exec is wrote in the pipe.
So when I get the answer, not all of the exec is wrote.

here is the part of the code concerned :

```
   switch(fork()){
        case -1:
            perror("fork");

        case 0:
            // redirection de l'entré standard
            close(fd[0]);
            dup2(fd[1], 1);
            dup2(fd[1], 2);
            close(fd[1]);
            // éxécution de la commande courrante.
            execvp(d->command[0], d->command);
            perror("execvp");

        default:
          // gère les processus zombies.
          if(wait(NULL) == -1){
                perror("wait");
          }
          char buffer[550000] = {0};
          unlink(d->pipe1);
          unlink(d->tube2);
          unlink(tube2);
          //création du tube nommé pour le client.
          if(mkfifo(tube2, 0644) != 0)
          {
              perror("mkfifo");
              fprintf(stderr, "Impossible de créer le tube nommé.\n");
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
          // ouverture de ce même tube
          if((d->entree_tube = open(tube2, O_WRONLY)) == -1)
          {
              perror("open");
              fprintf(stderr, "Impossible d'ouvrir l'entrée du tube nommé.\n");
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
          close(fd[1]);
          // lecture du résultat de la commande stocké dans fd[0]
          while (read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer)) != 0)
          {
              //écriture du résultat dans l'entré du tube.
             if(write(d->entree_tube, buffer, strlen(buffer)) == -1){
                perror("write");
             }
             //réinitialisation du buffer stockant une partie du résultat de la commande.
             memset (buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
          }
          // on regarde si il y a eu le mot clé "fin" pour alerter la client que la commande est terminé
          // et on redonne la main à un autre client tentant de se connecter au démon.

   }
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The parent can `wait()` or `waitpid()` for the child process writing to the pipe, but if it is the parent who is responsible for reading from the pipe then you should avoid that, and instead wait only after the child closes its end of the pipe (which it will do when it terminates if it doesn't do it before).  Otherwise, you risk deadlock as a result of the pipe buffer filling to capacity, with no one prepared to drain it.

Comment: So how can I avoid that? May I don't wait?

Comment: In any event, you shouldn't need to wait for the writer to finish writing before the reader starts reading.  Instead, you should use a read loop -- as indeed you do -- and keep reading until you receive all the data you expect or else encounter EOF or an error.  You do want to wait eventually, but not while you have any other responsibilities to the child.

Comment: I don't immediately see the source of your problem.  You are more likely to get a useful answer if you edit your question to present a [mcve] that captures your situation.  Quite possibly the nature of the problem is not what you think it is.

Comment: Indeed, I don't know how to ask it properly ^^, but I tried not to wait as you asked, but it doesn't resolve anything, and I don't see how can I read again datas by an other loop of read.

Comment: Your `switch` statement seems to be missing the `break` statements.

Comment: I added it, but doesn't resolve the problem ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried not to wait as you asked, but it doesn't resolve anything, and I don't see how can I read again datas by an other loop of read.

You don't need *an other loop of read* - the read loop you already have is just fine. You only have to move the `wait()` call behind that read loop. That's what John Bollinger meant when he wrote: *You do want to wait eventually, but not while you have any other responsibilities to the child.*